# which java version to install Windows x86,Windows x64 so that it will run on both 32 bit and 64 bit

Tags: java, windows

when i go to download page of the java there are two version for java

```
Windows x86 
Windows x64
```

How to find out which version is suitable for installation ?

Comment: If your machine is 64 bit you don't need the 32 bit version. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: x86 will run on both 64 and 32 bit also ? or x64 will run on both version @EJP

Comment: You are asking what software should you install on a 64-bit machine such that it will also run on a 32-bit machine. The question doesn't make sense.

Comment: this is simple any single java installation version which i can execute on any window version which could be 64 bit or 32 bit . Single exe file which can be used in both case

Comment: So why are you asking what to install on a 64-bit machine?

Comment: ok i have asked question in a wrong way . I will edit it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your OS is windows 32 bit then download `Windows x86` version. If your OS is windows 64 bit then download `Windows x64` version.

Java is platform independent. If you use platform independent libraries when developing; Your app will run on both 32 and 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a way to to check which architecture is your system through command prompt

```
wmic os get osarchitecture
```

Run this on your command prompt and you will get

```
"32-bit" or "64-bit".
```

and download the respective exe.